# Why is ffprobe showing N/A for bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate

I am transcoding a video from VP9/opus webm to H.264/aac mp4. I'd like to maintain bitrate or reduce bitrate if either the audio bitrate > 128k or the file becomes larger than 5MB.

So I try to query the  bitrate of the source audio stream in my video. However, it gives me N/A for the bitrate. (Also for the video stream by the way.)

`$  ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams myvid.webm`

```
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=opus
codec_long_name=Opus (Opus Interactive Audio Codec)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=-7
start_time=-0.007000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:DURATION=00:02:48.161000000
[/STREAM]
```

What gives? Shouldn't the bitrate always be known???

Comment: The bitrate of the different streams is written in the global header at the beginning of the file. With variable bitrate codecs, the final average bitrate is known only at the end of the encoding. The encoding software could rewind the file to write these informations, but probably not all of them are doing so.